# MPV with MMAL does not open application window

Tags: raspbian, video, ffmpeg

I've built mpv on the raspberry pi 3b+ (stretch-2018-06-27) using the following procedure from:

- [No OpenGL hardware rendering using

  mpv](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57847/no-opengl-hardware-rendering-using-mpv)
- [Quick & Easy: Hardware Accelerated MPV on Raspberry Pi 1/2/3 &

  Zero](https://nwgat.ninja/quick-easy-compiling-mpv-for-raspberry-pi/)

Run Updates

```
sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo rpi-update
```

increase memory ( advanced options > Memory Split > 256 )

```
sudo raspic-config
```

Restart then run the following (I added a few new installations due to errors, libmp3lame-dev and libx264-dev)

```
sudo apt-get install -y gperf bison flex autoconf automake make texinfo help2man libtool libtool-bin ncurses-dev git yasm mercurial cmake cmake-curses-gui libfribidi-dev checkinstall libfontconfig1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libgles2-mesa-dev gnutls-dev libsmbclient-dev libpulse-dev libbluray-dev libdvdread-dev libluajit-5.1-dev libjpeg-dev libv4l-dev libcdio-cdda-dev libcdio-paranoia-dev libmp3lame-dev libx264-dev

git clone https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv-build.git

cd mpv-build

echo "--enable-libx264
--enable-libmp3lame
--enable-mmal
--enable-gpl
--disable-v4l2-m2m" > ffmpeg_options

export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/vc/lib
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/vc/lib/pkgconfig/

./rebuild -j4
sudo scripts/mpv-install
```

## Problem

Everything seems to compile, but when I run a video with the command

```
sudo mpv-build/mpv/build/mpv --hwdec=mmal --vo=rpi ElephantsDream.mp4
```

Then no application is opened. The command line continues to show the video playing

[image]

The mpv log file doesn't seem to have produced any errors

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [the manual they linked](https://mpv.io/manual/master/):

> ## VIDEO OUTPUT DRIVERS
>
> Video output drivers are interfaces to different video output
>   facilities. The syntax is:
>
> `--vo=<driver1,driver2,...[,]>`
>       Specify a priority list of video output drivers to be used.
>
> If the list has a trailing ,, mpv will fall back on drivers not
>   contained in the list.
>
> ...
>
> ....
>
> **rpi (Raspberry Pi)**
>
> Native video output on the Raspberry Pi using the MMAL API.
>
> This is deprecated. Use `--vo=gpu` instead, which is the default and
>   provides the same functionality. The rpi VO will be removed in mpv
>   0.23.0. Its functionality was folded into `--vo=gpu`, which now uses RPI hardware decoding by treating it as a hardware overlay (without
>   applying GL filtering). Also to be changed in 0.23.0: the `--fs` flag
>   will be reset to "no" by default (like on the other platforms).
>
> The following deprecated global options are supported by this video
>   output:
>
> **`--rpi-display=<number>`**   Select the display number on which
>   the video overlay should be shown (default: 0).
>
> **`--rpi-layer=<number>`**   Select the dispmanx layer on which the video overlay should be shown (default: -10). Note that mpv will also use the 2 layers above the selected layer, to handle the window background and OSD. Actual video rendering will happen on the layer above the selected layer.
>
> **`--rpi-background=<yes|no>`**
>     Whether to render a black background behind the video (default: no). Normally it's better to kill the console framebuffer instead, which gives better performance.
>
> **`--rpi-osd=<yes|no>`**
>     Enabled by default. If disabled with no, no OSD layer is created. This also means there will be no subtitles rendered.

Otherwise you could try the `--hwdec=rpi` the answers suggests for some reason!

Comment: definitely useful, but even with --vo=gpu (or/& --hwdec=rpi) the application window still wont open

Comment: going to add another note, but though it is officially listed as deprecated, I get an error `Failed initializing any suitable GPU context!` on top of my original error when I use --vo=gpu instead of --vo=rpi